# What is the gcc equivalent option for the -qfuncsect option of XL compiler of AIX?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-options, size-reduction

XL Compiler of AIX seems to have the [-qfuncsect](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Fruoptfun.htm) option which places each function in a seperate object control section with the effect that when the final executable is created it helps in removing unwanted functions.

Is there an equivalent option for the same in gcc? I am unable to find the same.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? As far as I can see on my platform (linux) and gcc the final executable already has only the functions that are necessary.

Comment: I am not able to achieve whatever you are getting on VxWorks (MIPS). Is it not true that if a file contains 5 functions and my application uses only 2, then the other 3 also will get linked in? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-ffunction-sections
-fdata-sections
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: Should I be passing some options to linker also when I use these options with the compiler? I want this to work on VxWorks(MIPS and some more architectures).

Comment: It also says in this page in the explanation for these options that linker will produce larger object and executable files. Larger object files is fine, but why larger executable files, the whole point of this exercise is to reduce the executable size right?

Comment: You can use -Wl to pass arguments to the linker if you're using gcc. What you should send to the linker is --gc-sections. So besides the above mentions you should also have -Wl,--gc-sections

Answer (score 1):

See [-ffunction-sections](http://elinux.org/Function_sections)